# The Infamous Loop Opportunity

Tags: javascript

[This page](http://robertnyman.com/2008/10/09/explaining-javascript-scope-and-closures/) talks about the Infamous Loop Problem:

```
function addLinks () {
    for (var i=0, link; i<5; i++) {
        link = document.createElement("a");
        link.innerHTML = "Link " + i;
        link.onclick = function () {
            alert(i);
        };
        document.body.appendChild(link);
    }
}
window.onload = addLinks;
```

And one solution:

```
function addLinks () {
    for (var i=0, link; i<5; i++) {
        link = document.createElement("a");
        link.innerHTML = "Link " + i;
        link.onclick = function (num) {
            return function () {
                alert(num);
            };
        }(i);
        document.body.appendChild(link);
    }
}
window.onload = addLinks;
```

Here's my question: Is the infamous loop problem still a problem if the function you are calling is outside of the parent function (in example, outside of addLinks)?

```
function addLinks () {
    for (var i=0, link; i<5; i++) {
        link = document.createElement("a");
        link.innerHTML = "Link " + i;
        link.onclick = Outside(i);
        document.body.appendChild(link);
    }
}
function Outside(i) {
    alert(i);
};
window.onload = addLinks;
```

I think it will because the problem is created because addLinks isn't created yet when onclick is being called as a function.  So putting the function Outside of addLInks should alleviate the infamous loop problem, no?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem in your code is that it doesn't work.

```
link.onclick = Outside(i);
```

doesn't bind a function, as `Outside(i)` returns undefined.

A similar, working solution would be to define `Outside` as

```
function Outside(i) {
    return function() {
       alert(i);
    }
};
```

it would work for the same reason your second code works : calling the function `Outside` creates a new scope for the variable `i` (it's called a closure).

Any solution you'll build from your loop will probably involve more than just a function call : it'll need the declaration of a variable, either with the `var` keyword or as an argument of that function.

Answer (score 2):

```
link.onclick = Outside(i);
```

That will actually call `Outside(i)` rather than set the listener equal to that function with that default value. Various toolkits like Ext provide a way to create delegates similar to what dystroy showed. For example, in Ext 3.X you could do this:

link.onclick = Outside.createDelegate(link, [i]) to create a delegate that has `link` as the `this` context and `i` as the default parameter to `Outside`.

To make your example work, you'd need to do this:

```
function Outside(i) {
    return function() { alert(i); }
};
```

Answer (score 2):

The code you have written will not run I believe.

Outside does not return anything.  So calling Outside(i) will return undefined.  Which means you are setting link.onclick=undefined.